# Timebox Zkoss format hh:mm

Tags: java, zk

Is there any easy option to extend the timebox that i can use more then 23h?
I would need a input of hh:mm without the restrictions of a day.
It should be an easy way to enter a big industrial minute value for example instead of 3610minutes -> 60h:10m

The way, that i set the date format to yyyy:mm and convert via binder is too ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I used a bit js, getter and setter with binder and 2 intboxes.

```
jq('.min').keyup(function() {
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) >= 60) {
    $(this).val(59)
    }
});
```

`<intbox value="@{mission.hour}" constraint="no negative"/> : <intbox sclass="min" value="@{mission.minute}" constraint="no negative"/>`